# PyDev flags in error any import or method call that begin with org.jboss.as

Tags: jboss, pydev, jython

Env:
eclipse 4.3 on win 7

pydev 2.8.1_2013072611

jython 2.5.3, 2.5.4rc1, 2.7beta1

I'm trying to develop some jython scripts for jboss eap 6.1 cli and i'm facing what looks like a parsing problem.

Using 2.5 grammar with any of the releases of jython, anything in the scripts that begin with org.jboss.as (imports or method calls like:

```
import org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContextFactory
```

or

```
org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContextFactory.getInstance().newCommandContext()
```

) has the embedded `as` portion blue colored as if it was the 'as' language keyword. When launched the script execute without problems.

Using grammar 2.6 or 2.7 with jython 2.7beta1 (or with any previous release, even if it doesn't make too much sense) the 'as' is enforced as keyword because, besides being still blue colored, the import, or any subsequent method calls, if the import is commented, are marked in error with messages like

```
Encountered "as" at line 7, column 18. Was expecting:     <NAME> ...
```

When launched, again the script executes without problem.

Any idea if this can be a pydev or jython problem?

Thanks,
Gabriele

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that PyDev is not covering exactly Jython semantics works on this (only Python semantics which disallow the 'as').

Gramar 2.5 works because I believe Python did accept it at that point and made it invalid later on -- and Jython is not following the same semantics (a different outcome could be that Jython itself shouldn't allow it and export the 'as' module under a different name).

So, please create a ticket at the PyDev tracker at http://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/ to fix that for later Jython versions.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, opened ticket #190.